# While using an Intersection Observer, is it possible to trigger an intersection before the image is on the page?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, intersection-observer

I'm currently implement lazy load. Without lazy load, My app is experiences a major slow down when displaying over 100 images. So the solution was to change the image source once it's visible.

However, it triggers a bit too late as I'm loading an image once the images intersects. It causes some flickering and was wondering if I can mess with the rootMargin somehow where it would trigger intersecting way before it actually reaches the actual viewport.

I have tried using positive and negative margins such as: '1000px' '0px 0px 100%'. Not exactly sure what I'm messing with or if there is another work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using virtualization for this, instead of intersections observers that you handle manually.

If you use react check out:
[React Window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-window)

If you use vanilla js or jquery consider:
[Virtualized list](https://github.com/clauderic/virtualized-list)

Virtualization helps you fix that problem automatically.
Learn more about virtualization [here](https://snorkel.ai/web-virtualization-optimizing-data-intensive-app-performance/#:%7E:text=Windowing%20%5B1%5D%2C%20also%20referred,rendering%20only%20elements%20in%20view.)